# geosparql performance issue

Tags: sparql, graphdb

I have a triple store that has 150 million statements and all of them include geometries. I'm currently using GraphDB triple store and its geosparql extension. The endpoint is just doing weird things when combining geosparql and filter queries. The GraphDB side has confirmed that there are some issues with their geosparql extension. I'm just wondering if this is normal with geosparql queries in general when combined with filter queries. If geosparql should be much faster (for example in virtuoso), I might just migrate to virtuoso. Otherwise, I might need to come up with other solutions. This might lead to another more general question, when dealing with geographic data, what are the efficient ways to do spatial queries?

Here's an example of the performance issue.

This query (just a filter query with no geosparql components) here will take 2-15 sec (which is still a very long time):

```
PREFIX geo-pos: <http://www.w3.org/2003/01/geo/wgs84_pos#>
PREFIX geo: <http://www.opengis.net/ont/geosparql#>
PREFIX geof: <http://www.opengis.net/def/function/geosparql/>
PREFIX xsd: <http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema#>
PREFIX sf: <http://www.opengis.net/def/sf#>
select ?a
WHERE {
    ?a :hasPrimaryName ?o . 
    FILTER (contains(?o,'Paris'))
}
```

This query (using the geosparql extension in GraphDB) will take about 5 sec with or without the limit:

```
PREFIX geof: <http://www.opengis.net/def/function/geosparql/>
PREFIX geo-pos: <http://www.w3.org/2003/01/geo/wgs84_pos#>
PREFIX geo: <http://www.opengis.net/ont/geosparql#>
PREFIX omgeo: <http://www.ontotext.com/owlim/geo#>
PREFIX xsd: <http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema#>
select *
WHERE {
    ?a geo:hasGeometry ?aGeom .
    ?aGeom geo:asWKT ?aWKT .
    FILTER (geof:sfWithin(?aWKT, '''<http://www.opengis.net/def/crs/OGC/1.3/CRS84> POLYGON((1.549072265625 49.468124067331644,3.31787109375 49.468124067331644,3.31787109375 48.436489955944154,1.549072265625 48.436489955944154,1.549072265625 49.468124067331644))'''^^geo:wktLiteral))
}
```

Combining both queries will time out (after 60sec) whether we use a limit or not:

```
PREFIX geo-pos: <http://www.w3.org/2003/01/geo/wgs84_pos#>
PREFIX geo: <http://www.opengis.net/ont/geosparql#>
PREFIX geof: <http://www.opengis.net/def/function/geosparql/>
PREFIX xsd: <http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema#>
PREFIX sf: <http://www.opengis.net/def/sf#>
select ?a
WHERE {
    ?a geo:hasGeometry ?aGeom .
    ?aGeom geo:asWKT ?aWKT .
FILTER (geof:sfWithin(?aWKT, '''<http://www.opengis.net/def/crs/OGC/1.3/CRS84> POLYGON((1.549072265625 49.468124067331644,3.31787109375 49.468124067331644,3.31787109375 48.436489955944154,1.549072265625 48.436489955944154,1.549072265625 49.468124067331644))'''^^geo:wktLiteral))
    ?a :hasPrimaryName ?o . FILTER (contains(?o,'Paris'))
}
```

Since we are typically using the triple store as a server for our web map interface and we are doing a lot of spatial queries in our web map, the efficiency of geosparql queries is important to us. Querying time such as 60s is not acceptable to us. Is there a way to improve this situation? Either with the server side (geosparql queries) or with the web map side (we are using javascript)? Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

GraphDB's GeoSPARQL support uses an index for predicate-based queries (e.g. `?a geo:sfWithin ?b`) while function-based queries (e.g. `filter(geof:sfWithin(?a, ?b))`) require a full scan. You can rewrite your queries to take advantage of the predicate index, e.g.

```
PREFIX geo-pos: <http://www.w3.org/2003/01/geo/wgs84_pos#>
PREFIX geo: <http://www.opengis.net/ont/geosparql#>
PREFIX geof: <http://www.opengis.net/def/function/geosparql/>
PREFIX xsd: <http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema#>
PREFIX sf: <http://www.opengis.net/def/sf#>
select ?a
WHERE {
    ?a geo:hasGeometry ?aGeom .
    ?aGeom geo:asWKT ?aWKT .
    ?aWKT geo:sfWithin '''<http://www.opengis.net/def/crs/OGC/1.3/CRS84> POLYGON((1.549072265625 49.468124067331644,3.31787109375 49.468124067331644,3.31787109375 48.436489955944154,1.549072265625 48.436489955944154,1.549072265625 49.468124067331644))'''^^geo:wktLiteral .
}
```

Note that using literals as the object of the predicate `geo:sfWithin` is a GraphDB-extension and not a standard GeoSPARQL feature.

In your full query you also use `contains(?o, 'Paris')`. This is a slow operation as it requires a full scan. If you need full-text search you could try one of the GraphDB Lucene Connector, see http://graphdb.ontotext.com/documentation/free/lucene-graphdb-connector.html for more information. The enterprise edition of GraphDB also has connectors for Solr and Elasticsearch.

Comment: Thanks for the suggestion, but I changed my second query in the question to use "?a geo:sfWithin ?b", it still takes 54s and returns no results. The same query with the filter does return results.